# Request rejected with Options when fetching the VPCs with Authorization header

Tags: authorization, ibm-cloud, vpc, ibm-iam

Generating the request to list the vpc details with IAM token which is kept in authorization header  - The request has been generated from React App -

```
https://urls.cloud.ibm.com/v1/vpcs?version=2019-08-06&generation=1
```

Configuration

```
config = {
        headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer lmtmlmlm",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      }
    }
```

The request was failed during the pre-flight request, it seems that the browser request headers are asking the server for permissions to make the actual request.

Can you suggest to overcome the problem.

Comment: Are you following the docs here? https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/vpc-on-classic

Comment: @data_henrik, Yes, I am referring to the same documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The instructions here worked well for me: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/vpc-on-classic?topic=vpc-on-classic-creating-a-vpc-using-the-rest-apis

I noticed you used the url: https://urls.cloud.ibm.com while these docs suggested https://us-south.iaas.cloud.ibm.com

```
rias_endpoint="https://us-south.iaas.cloud.ibm.com"
iam_token='Bearer zzzrandomstuff...eyJraWQiOiIyMDE5MDUxMyIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In'
version="2019-05-31"
curl -X GET "$rias_endpoint/v1/vpcs?version=$version&generation=1" -H "Authorization: $iam_token"
```

Comment: Yes, i have used the correct URL which is mentioned in the documentation as "https://us-south.iaas.cloud.ibm.com". However, i was requesting it through browser with my own react application, browser itself sends pre-flight request to server to ensure CORS. Hence, the next subsequent request was failing from browser. I was able to execute it well with curl. The problem is generated when it is implemented through UI app like react etc from browser. hope it clarifies. thanks